# Programmatically sleep Apple TV on tvos

Tags: tvos, apple-tv

I'd like to have a sleep timer within my own tvos app. Is there a way to enable/disable sleeping on tvos?

I know you disable sleeping using:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

But is there a way to then enable sleep right away when a timer finishes?