# How do we increase or decrease brightness of a tvOS app using Swift 3? Also, how do we implement a customized sleep timer here?

Tags: ios, swift, tvos

I am building a tvOS app using swift3. It is an app where video plays in a loop with sounds. I need to include brightness control, Speed control and a sleep timer.

This is my code:

```
@IBOutlet var downBtn: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var upBtnn: UIButton!



 private var brightness: CGFloat?
    var scale: Double = 0
    let maxScale: Double = 1


 @IBAction func increaseBtn(_ sender: Any) {


        if scale > maxScale {
            return
        }

        scale += 0.10
        uiscreenbrightness(UInt(scale))

    }

    @IBAction func decreaseBright(_ sender: Any) {


        if scale <= 0 {
            return
        }

        scale -= 0.10
        uiscreenbrightness(UInt(scale))

    }

    func uiscreenbrightness(_ scale: UInt) {

//       UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(scale)


    }
```

But this gives me an error " Brightness is unavailable". 
How do I include the brightness functionality?

Also, this app has a customized timer functionality. So when the user sets a time, the TV will sleep after that. Is it possible to do this?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: So are you trying to use `UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(scale)`?

Comment: @paper1111 Yes I am!! Is it correct?

Comment: You can not change brightness of TVOS app and also above methods is only for iOS not for tvOS.

Comment: @CodeChanger Oh I see.. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set the brightness. From [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscreen/1617830-brightness), the section about the SDK only has iOS 5+
[image]

Personally, I think you cannot sleep the TV itself. Look at this question: [Programmatically sleep Apple TV on tvos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33639783/programmatically-sleep-apple-tv-on-tvos), there are no answers even after such a long time. A [basic google search](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=programmatically+sleep+apple+tv) returned completely irrelevant results.

As with the iPhone, this may be [updated later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779667/is-there-a-way-of-adjusting-the-screen-brightness-programmatically) and an API may be created. I will edit this once an API is available.

EDIT: You may want to try to [give feedback to apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/) (suggestion only)

Comment: Oh I see. So that means we can only go for default TV brightness and timer? Thanks for the details by the way!!